# How to mock smart contract with hardhat and ethers v6

Tags: hardhat, testing, unittesting, mock, smock

I found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/127626/how-to-mock-smart-contract-function-for-testing-in-hardhat) 2 ways to mock Smart contract but they all limited to *ethers.js v5*:

- [@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat-waffle)
- [@defi-wonderland/smock](https://smock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html)

Today *hardhat-toolbox* is at *version 4* and migrated away from [hardhat-waffle](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/migrating-from-hardhat-waffle) to use *@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers*, supposedly a drop-in replacement, but it seems to be with no support for mocking. We've seen complains [here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2975)

At the time of this writing, is there any way to mock smart contract using *ethers v6* or I'd be force to downgrade my whole Dapp environement to *ethers v5*?

PS: Here is [github issue](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock/issues/187) to subscribe to with the hope that *smock* might bring supports to new *hardhat-toolbox* version

Comment: Having the same issue right now, smock doesn't seem to be actively developed anymore at all.

Comment: I ended up going for [foundry](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry) for most of my unittest